# What hand scores are impossible in Cribbage?

Tags: scoring, cribbage

It's very well known that 19 is an impossible score to achieve when counting your hand.

What are the other impossible to achieve scores?  I've read 25, 26, 27.  Does anyone know the answer authoritatively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All scores from 0 to 29 are [possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cribbage#The_show) with the exception of 19, 25, 26 and 27, as already mentioned.

Comment: In standard cribbage... several variations involve more cards. And with the caveat that you're only counting the hand, not the play phase points.

Comment: @Aramis Given that the question specifies counting your hand, seems logical

Answer (score -2):

Several sites state this truth.

For example:

http://www.rubl.com/rules/cribbage-statistics.html