# What's the highest score that can be achieved by pegging?

Tags: cribbage

Nearly every cribbage player knows that 29 is the highest-scoring hand that one can achieve, and that [19 and some others](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/what-hand-scores-are-impossible-in-cribbage) are impossible to score.

However, I'm curious to know what is the highest score one can achieve during the play of the cards (also known as "pegging"?  What cards would need to be played, in what order, and what would your opponent's pegged score be?  **This question is meant to exclude the final count of points in one's hand.**

I'm sure the answer probably differs between 2, 3, and 4-player games because there are more cards available when there are more players.  My question is focused on the two player game.  If anyone happens to have answers for the others as well though, those would be interesting to know.

Comment: This question can be improved.

Comment: @The Chaz - can you elaborate?

Comment: "The question does not show [enough] research effort" ... sure, it's subjective.

Comment: Finally realized where I went wrong in the wording of this question.  Updated.

Answer (score 12):

If you scroll down to ["Pegging Maximal Score"](http://www.rubl.com/rules/cribbage-statistics.html), they outline how the dealer can peg 30 points.

I found that page from [an answer to the question that you linked above](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/4505/1885)... not sure how you missed that!

---

Added:

> Joe O'Brien showed, that dealer can score 30 points (not 26 points as we stated before with a dealer's hand 4,4,4,7, pone's hand 4,8,10,K, and the jack as a starter).
>
> In Joe's example Dealer hand 7,7,4,4 ; Pone hand 7,7,4,4. Sequence of play is as follows:
>
> Pone 7 7 4 4
>
> Dealer 7 7 4 4
>
> Dealer Points 2 13 2 13
>
> Dealer Totals 2 15 17 30
>
> This example of dealer maximal cribbage hands is in the article based on the letter of Joe O'Brien.
>
> Update - Joe O'Brien showed that there is a hand that will give the
> pone a total of 24 in pegging. The Pone holding 5 5 4 4, and the
> Dealer holding 5 4 4 (na/). The Pone hits both the fifteen and the
> thirty-one, picking up a triple at the 15 mark and a pair and four of
> a kind on the way to the thirty-one mark. Kyle Graham showed, that
> pone can score 22 points (in opposite to other articles, that states
> max pone score is 18 points). Pone's hand: A, A, 3, 3; Dealer's hand
> A, 3, 3, NA. The sequence of play is A, A, A, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA; Pone
> gets 6+2+14 = 22 points. Later our player Kenneth Anderson showed,
> that the maximum cribbage scoring for Pone pegging is 23. Pone's hand:
> 5 (or 6) 4 4 4; Dealer's hand: 5 (or 6) 4 9 9 (9 9 could be any cards
> worth 9 or above). Total Pone points: 5+6+12 = 23 . More examples of
> pone maximal cribbage hands are in the article based on the letters of
> Joe O'Brien, Kyle Graham and Kenneth Anderson.

Comment: Could you please flesh this out with a bit more detail, as requested in the question?  Particularly, since the question explicitly asks for it, the answer should include at least one example of how the pegged score would be achieved and what the opponent's hand would look like - the data shouldn't just reside behind a link.

Answer (score 9):

The [Cribbage Statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cribbage_statistics) page answers this question, 78 for the dealer (hand + pegged + crib)

> The maximum number of points that can be scored in a single deal by the dealer in a two player game is 78 (pegging + hand + crib):
>
> Non-dealer is dealt 3 3 4 4 5 J and Dealer is dealt 3 3 4 4 5 5.
>
> Non-dealer discards J 5 to the crib (as ill-advised as this may be).
>
> Dealer discards 5 5 to the crib. Note that the J is suited to the remaining 5. The remaining 5 is cut.
>
> Play is 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 go. The dealer scores 29 total peg points.
>
> The dealer's hand is 3 3 4 4 5 = 20
>
> The dealer's crib is J(nobs) 5 5 5 5 = 29
>
> The total score for the dealer is 29 + 20 + 29 = 78.
>
> The maximum number of points that can be scored in a single deal by the non-dealer in a two player game is 48 (pegging + hand), with the following example :
>
> Non-dealer is dealt 5 5 4 4 crib crib and Dealer is dealt 4 4 5 9 crib crib. Cut card is a 6.
>
> Play is 5 5 5 4 4 4 4, with the Non-dealer pegging 24. The Non-dealer scores 24 in the hand for a total of 48 points.
>
> Combining this hand with the highest dealer hand, a standard 121 point game can be completed in just two deals.

Comment: I'm only looking for "pegged", but thanks.  Could you please flesh this out with a bit more detail, as requested in the question?  Particularly, since the question explicitly asks for it, the answer should include at least one example of how the pegged score would be achieved and what the opponent's hand would look like - the data shouldn't just reside behind a link.

Comment: @Iszi,if you were only interested in pegged then that is what you should have asked. the way the questioned is worded, you are asking about MAX total score per single deal. it would be weid if you were asking about winning the game 121-1 plus max score per deal.

Comment: The question could also be interpreted to be the highest possible score in a game, rather than a hand, which is 173 (peg to 120, St:5x H:Jx555=29, C:4466=24), or the highest one can get without counting one's hand (135... at 120, and score a double pair royal 15 on last card, for 12+2+1=15...)

Comment: @aramis, fair enough. My point was the question was badly worded, and I don't believe that the OP's interpretation can be arrived at from the way it is currently worded.

Comment: I've given this some more thought, and I'm not sure that this answer is necessarily accurate.  The section in the Wiki article is addressing the highest score a dealer can achieve between hand, pegging, and crib.  However, it is conceivable (possible or not, I don't know) that higher pegging scores can be achieved if one is not limiting themselves to a hand that reaches the highest score possible in one deal.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility for 32 points is if both players hold 6 6 7 7 and you are the dealer. First player plays 7, you play 7 for 2, they play 7 for 6, you play 7 for 12 and a go. 15. Then all the 6s get played for another 15 points. The extra 2 points being if a jack is flipped.

Comment: The jack flip is not scored during play (pegging), but rather scored before play when it is flipped.

Answer (score 0):

I pegged 26 points in a three hand game.  I kept ace ace 2 2.  I led ace, then ace, ace, ace, for 12, then king, 9, I played 2, then 2, 2, 2 for 14.

Answer (score -4):

Answer is thirty two. Each player is dealt two sevens and two sixes. Any jack is turned over. First card played is a seven. You can figure it out from there.

Comment: This answer just duplicates information that already exists in other answers.